# The word for pertaining to personality

Tags: suffixes, personality

We all know that the -al suffix creates the meaning of "pertaining to" or "relating to" or "of the kind" with a noun, e.g. social, fictional etc....
What I am looking for is a word for pertaining to personality. as I know the word "personal" means relating to person so that wouldn't be the answer. This sentence may be an example: "... The truth is that recent efforts have largely been focused on positive ethical and (pertaining to personality) characteristics..." where the context is moral psychology.
Any help is appreciated.
Regards

Comment: This is a good question, but do you have a particular example sentence that you're looking for the word to fit in? Because it is not totally out there that *personal* actually fits the bill. Thanks.

Comment: @RegDwigнt 
This sentence may be an example: "... The truth is that recent efforts have largely been focused on positive ethical and (pertaining to personality) characteristics..." where the context is moral psychology. Although this sentence can be rephrased, finding the word can be helpful in other contexts.

Comment: You may have to fudge with 'personality-related' (which seems quite idiomatic). I'm not sure it's not too obvious when thought of (though easily missable, of course) to be given as an ELU 'answer'. // I'm not sure how 'ethical' and 'personality[-related]' parallel each other, though obviously they're not as disparate as say 'political' and 'aqueous'.

Comment: What's wrong with "The truth is that recent efforts have largely been focused on positive ethical and personality characteristics.." ?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth
Thank you for you comment. Of course the word personality-related can in some way show the meaning, but it looks uni-dimensional, which means it merely refers to the "relating to" part, not all dimensions we refer to by -al suffix.
As for "ethical" and "personality-related", like I said, the context of the above mentioned sentence is moral psychology, in which ethical and personality-related parallel each other in numerous ways.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey
Ethical is an adjective and personality is a noun, wouldn't it be wrong grammatically if they go together?

Comment: Personality can be used as an adjective. Sometimes we use [a noun to describe another noun](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm). In that case, the first noun "acts as" an adjective - history teacher, race horse, ticket office, personality characteristics.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey
In this case, do we grammatically call the first word an adjective? or it simply works as an adjective and grammatically is a noun?
anyways, my main point was about an adjective (ethical) being connected to a noun (personality) using a conjunction (and). is it OK? if yes, can it be true about a noun and a verb?

Comment: No; '-related' is as general as it gets. Where there is any difference at all, the -al adjectives are usually more narrowly defined. 'Chemistry-related' (eg workers in the field, produced by noxious emissions, relating to two A-level papers ...) vs 'chemical'. 'Ethics-related' vs 'ethical'.  Relating to comics/comedy vs 'comical'. // Dictionary definitions for adjectives were once of the form 'of, like, or otherwise relating to ...'.

Comment: A noun acting as an adjective (or 'noun adjunct') functions as an adjective.

Comment: "about an adjective (ethical) being connected to a noun (personality) using a conjunction (and). is it OK? if yes, can it be true about a noun and a verb? – please provide an example or description of such a 'noun and verb' combination.

Comment: In 'a football manager', 'football' is still a noun (based upon deeper studies of how these constructions behave in differing contexts; the 'adjective' classification just loses out here, but it's a close thing). It acts as a premodifier of 'manager' in much the same way as an adjective would do. // In 'a steel bridge', the last I heard, Professors of Linguistics still could not agree on whether 'steel' should be considered a noun or an adjective. It's that tricky.)

Comment: @Pcboy In fact, if you are looking for a way of turning ‘personality’ into an adjective by way of an -al or ‘i-le’ ending, you are out of luck. First, personal’ already IS an adjective formed by the addition of ‘-al’ to the noun ‘person’.  I cannot think of any noun-turned-into-adjective-turned to-noun-turned-into-adjective.  I doubt whether one exists.  If I were to invent it, it would be ‘personalicity’.  But there are already enough monstrous creations like this without adding another, when Edwin A has given a simple alternative, in keeping with the now widespread use of nouns as adjectives

Comment: Doctors (at least in Britain) talk about people having a 'personality disorder'.

Comment: Thank you guys very very much, you shed a huge amount of light on the issue and now I have other options - with regard to word choosing to take advantage of.
Best regards

Comment: @Pcboy Your clarifications are hidden in the comments, which currently need to be expanded to see. Please edit your clarifications into the question so all the information is in one spot.

Answer (score 0):

With the great commentators' help, it turns out that the proper way for expressing "pertaining to" or "relating to" personality is [using a noun to describe a noun](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm) which means using "personality" itself as adjective or adding "- related" to "personality". There is no way to make an adjective out of "personality" using suffixes since they have been added to the word "person" already.